# How could I create an LPG indicator?

Tags: smart-home, kitchen-appliances, safety

The LPG gas is commonly used for cooking, and it is a very common practice to cut off the gas supply by closing the valve.

Suppose I am away from my home and I forgot to check whether my LPG supply is cut-off. Is it possible to make a device that can email me a status of LPG supply whether on or off, and if possible switch it off remotely?

[**Related**](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/17/73)

Comment: Using a gas sensor may be simpler, and more foolproof in that you could detect a leak or failure of the shut-off.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever Yeah that'd be great, but I have doubts 1)How can we connect that device(gas sensor) to the network. 2) How to cut the gas supply.

Comment: It depends on your level of expertise with electronics (which I am sure is going to be an interesting spectrum here) but there are various kinds of "MQ-[n]" gas sensors that are cheap and produce a simple analog value (I think for LPG, at least MQ-5 and MQ-6 are good). So you would have to connect that to something with wifi/radio, e.g., an ESP8266 or ZigBee type thing -- it would not cost much, again the major issue would be know-how.

Comment: I think tthis is off-topic. There is nothing in the question to make it specificly IoT.

Comment: I think this is too broad. There are any sorts of approaches that could reasonably used to do it. However almost all you build yourself could easier be attached to the valve itself.

Comment: The answer is obviously yes, it's possible, but to go beyond that we'd need to know what hardware you need to interface with and what you're doing with it (what are you looking to purchase vs designing yourself?).

Answer (score 8):

**The quick answer is yes, it is possible**.

You can add a pressure sensor and a servo-actuated valve to your gas line and sample / control them via your choice if micro-controller. You should take every precaution to do this properly - preferably with the assistance of a properly licensed contractor, since leaky gas lines can cause massive damage to life and property.

You'll also want to take precautions on the software side so that only you can control the [Servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism), such as two-way encryption and authentication.

Comment: Jhon, I think you should improve your answer by adding relevant diagrams or adding more information about things like servo-actuated valve

Comment: This would also be very dangerous.  For example, for petrol pumps, the servos and all electronics have to comply with strict standards to ensure there is never any spark.  There is also a limit on the amount of current you can use.